# What computer vision library should I use for 3D mapping?

Tags: 3d, mapping, computer-vision, point-cloud-library, slam-algorithm

Numerous 3D mapping applications were researched and implemented in MAVs. I would like to know what library is used to be able to map an indoor environment in 3D? Is PCL enough?

Answer (score 0):

One proposal would be to try out the **kinfu_app** of PCL.

[See the documentation with explanation here](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/using_kinfu_large_scale.php)